# How to read a character-string in a column of a data-set

Tags: arrays, r, database, string

I don't know how to use read.table command when the data I want to read has some columns with character strings.

I have a .dat file that contains 28 columns and 100 rows.

```
  Año  Mes  Día Hora  Min      SO2      NOx       CO       O3     PM10    PM2.5     VelV     DirV     Temp   SO2_MH   NOx_MH    CO_MH    O3_MH  PM10_MH PM2.5_MH   Pred_SO2   Pred_NOx     PredBin_SO2     PredBin_NOx  CodM_SO2  CodM_NOx          Mensaje_SO2          Mensaje_NOx
 2018    5   15   16   38    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    99.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00      -1.00      -1.00           -1.00           -1.00         0         0                                          
 2018    5   15   16   39    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    99.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00      -1.00      -1.00           -1.00           -1.00         0         0                                          
 2018    5   16   11   29     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00     1.13   259.00    14.50     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00       4.15       7.51            0.03            0.00         1         1        No hay alarma        No hay alarma
 2018    5   16   11   30     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00     1.13   259.00    14.50     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00       4.15       7.51            0.03            0.00         1         1        No hay alarma        No hay alarma
```

When I try to read the data it reads ok the first 26 columns, but the 27th and 28th ones are "No" and "hay", so I want to read the full sentence in the 27th column and do the same in the 28th one.

This is what I use

```
min <- read.table("min.dat",header=T, fill = TRUE)
```

But I suppose I have to use the quote parameter somehow...
(I use fill=TRUE because some of this character strings are blank).

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the first few lines of your file?

Comment: Is there a column separator in the file? Maybe the tab character `"\t"`.

Comment: @Rohit Yes, sorry for not doing it before, now I think it is more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this usinf `readr::read_fwf()` if you can specify the start and end positions of each column:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
fname <- 'sample.txt'
write_file(
  '  Año  Mes  Día Hora  Min      SO2      NOx       CO       O3     PM10    PM2.5     VelV     DirV     Temp   SO2_MH   NOx_MH    CO_MH    O3_MH  PM10_MH PM2.5_MH   Pred_SO2   Pred_NOx     PredBin_SO2     PredBin_NOx  CodM_SO2  CodM_NOx          Mensaje_SO2          Mensaje_NOx
 2018    5   15   16   38    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    99.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00      -1.00      -1.00           -1.00           -1.00         0         0                                          
 2018    5   15   16   39    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    99.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00    -1.00      -1.00      -1.00           -1.00           -1.00         0         0                                          
 2018    5   16   11   29     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00     1.13   259.00    14.50     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00       4.15       7.51            0.03            0.00         1         1        No hay alarma        No hay alarma
 2018    5   16   11   30     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00     1.13   259.00    14.50     4.15     7.51     0.33    77.00    13.00     5.00       4.15       7.51            0.03            0.00         1         1        No hay alarma        No hay alarma                         ',
  fname
)

hdr <- read_lines(fname,n_max = 1)
cnames <- hdr %>%
  trimws()%>%
  strsplit('\\s+')%>%
  unlist()

m <- gregexpr('\\S(?=\\s|$)',hdr,perl = T) # Find end position of columns
epos <-unlist(m)
spos <- lag(epos+1,1,default = 1)

read_fwf(fname,fwf_positions(start = spos,end = epos,col_names = cnames),skip = 1)
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   Mensaje_SO2 = col_character(),
#>   Mensaje_NOx = col_character()
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.
#> # A tibble: 4 x 28
#>     Año   Mes   Día  Hora   Min   SO2   NOx    CO    O3  PM10 PM2.5  VelV
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  2018     5    15    16    38 -1    -1    -1       -1    -1    -1 -1   
#> 2  2018     5    15    16    39 -1    -1    -1       -1    -1    -1 -1   
#> 3  2018     5    16    11    29  4.15  7.51  0.33    77    13     5  1.13
#> 4  2018     5    16    11    30  4.15  7.51  0.33    77    13     5  1.13
#> # … with 16 more variables: DirV <dbl>, Temp <dbl>, SO2_MH <dbl>,
#> #   NOx_MH <dbl>, CO_MH <dbl>, O3_MH <dbl>, PM10_MH <dbl>, PM2.5_MH <dbl>,
#> #   Pred_SO2 <dbl>, Pred_NOx <dbl>, PredBin_SO2 <dbl>, PredBin_NOx <dbl>,
#> #   CodM_SO2 <dbl>, CodM_NOx <dbl>, Mensaje_SO2 <chr>, Mensaje_NOx <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I get 28 columns with the expected values

Comment: Thank you, but I still get an error, probably because "Año" uses "ñ" and "Día" uses " í ". The error I get is when I use the "cnames" part, I get the following message: "Error in sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8".