# How to read data in R with two headers and variables separated with blank spaces

Tags: r, file, import, data-manipulation

I have a problem since I need to read some data files that have a strange structure and I don't have any idea of how to read them. The data consist of two headers where the first one starts on the fourth column.
The values of each column are numbers except four rows that have a character string separated with blank spaces (I cannot modify the data since I only have reading rights on the data). I need to read the values, I don't care if I omit the names on the headers or if the character string gets a value depending on the message which can be of four types. With being able to read the values of a selected column it would be alright, even if the colums have no names.

This is an example of what kind of file I want to read, they are `.dat` files:

```
                                  B1         B1              B1               B1                   B1                 B1                     B2         B2              B2                       B2                   B2                   B2         
  Year  Month  Day  Hour  Min   Number1   Number2         Number3           Message             Number4            Message2                Number1   Number2          Number3                 Message              Number4              Message2  
  2019    4     9    8    53     3.29      46.31           0.03      There are no problems         1        There are no problems           3.00       2.00            0.00                                           1          There are no problems       
  2019    4     9    8    54     3.19      46.17           0.03      There are no problems         1        There are two problems          3.00       2.00            0.00             There are no problems         1          There are no problems  
  2019    4     9    8    55     3.15      46.17           0.03      There are no problems         1                                        3.00       3.92            0.00             There are no problems         1          There are three problems
```

I got solution for how to read datafiles with blank spaces here:     [How to read a character-string in a column of a data-set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56235016/how-to-read-a-character-string-in-a-column-of-a-data-set), but with the two header form starting in  the four column I have no idea on what to do...
Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: May you bake an example of what you would get as output ?

Comment: @Tensibai I don't really care as long as I can access to one specific column of the data. It can be a data frame, a table, a matrix... I just want to be able to access for example the sixth column (with ```data[,6]``` if it were a data frame for example or with ```data[6]``` if somehow one manages to get each column as an element...)

Answer (score 0):

you'are on the right track. `read_lines()` has an argument called `skip`. This lets you just skip the first row. You will get warnings, since the column-names are not unique, but it seems you don't care too much about that ;-)

So building on what you had found already (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56238232/1842673):

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
fname <- 'sample.txt'
write_file("                                B1         B1              B1               B1                   B1                 B1                     B2         B2              B2                       B2                   B2                   B2         
  Year  Month  Day  Hour  Min   Number1   Number2         Number3           Message             Number4            Message2                Number1   Number2          Number3                 Message              Number4              Message2  
  2019    4     9    8    53     3.29      46.31           0.03      There are no problems         1        There are no problems           3.00       2.00            0.00                                           1          There are no problems       
  2019    4     9    8    54     3.19      46.17           0.03      There are no problems         1        There are two problems          3.00       2.00            0.00             There are no problems         1          There are no problems  
  2019    4     9    8    55     3.15      46.17           0.03      There are no problems         1                                        3.00       3.92            0.00             There are no problems         1          There are three problems  "
 ,
  fname
)

hdr <- read_lines(fname,n_max = 1,skip=1) #skips over the first line
cnames <- hdr %>%
  trimws()%>%
  strsplit('\\s+')%>%
  unlist()

m <- gregexpr('\\S(?=\\s|$)',hdr,perl = T) # Find end position of columns
epos <-unlist(m)
spos <- lag(epos+1,1,default = 1)

read_fwf(fname,fwf_positions(start = spos,end = epos,col_names = cnames),skip = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! But do you know if I could,somehow, skip the first column? In my original data, the first variable contains a character invalid in UTF-8, so I get the error ```Error in sub(re, "", x, perl = TRUE) : input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
```, but I cannot change the encoding of the file.